# Installing ffmpeg + dependencies on AWS Linux AMI (repo issues)

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, sdl

I'm installing `ffmpeg` to run on an Amazon linux AMI, and have added the `rpmforge` repo and the `dag` repo.  Here are some guidelines I'm using for reference:  [TWoZaO](http://www.twozao.com/2010/04/ffmpeg-installation-step-by-step-guide.html) and [Razuna](http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/FFMpeg+Installation+on+CentOS+and+RedHat)

The rpmforge repo has `ffmpeg`, but if you try to install it then it will complain that is missing dependencies (for me `libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit)`). Regardless I will install `ffmpeg from svn so I can be sure to enable the options I want (namely`libx264`).  It seems strange to me though that SDL is not in`rpmforge`or`dag`, and in according to both of my references above, it should be there.  I tried to grab it manually from [here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/SDL-devel-1.2.10-8.el5.x86_64.rpm), but it needs these dependencies, so no-go:

```
> error: Failed dependencies:   SDL =
> 1.2.10-8.el5 is needed by SDL-devel-1.2.10-8.el5.x86_64
>   alsa-lib-devel is needed by
> SDL-devel-1.2.10-8.el5.x86_64
>   libGL-devel is needed by
> SDL-devel-1.2.10-8.el5.x86_64
>   libGLU-devel is needed by
> SDL-devel-1.2.10-8.el5.x86_64
>   libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit) is needed by
> SDL-devel-1.2.10-8.el5.x86_64
>   libX11-devel is needed by
> SDL-devel-1.2.10-8.el5.x86_64
>   libXext-devel is needed by
> SDL-devel-1.2.10-8.el5.x86_64
>   libXrandr-devel is needed by
> SDL-devel-1.2.10-8.el5.x86_64
>   libXrender-devel is needed by
> SDL-devel-1.2.10-8.el5.x86_64
>   libXt-devel is needed by
> SDL-devel-1.2.10-8.el5.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that the missing dependency is in the centOS repository, which in amazon ec2 is not included. I added the repository and was able to configure and install ffmpeg.  For anyone doing the same I recommend the Razuna guide I mentioned in the question : http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/FFMpeg+Installation+on+CentOS+and+RedHat

( Thanks to rubberman on linux forums for the solution )

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, this one did it for me (replacing i686 with x86_64): https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=196807

Comment: Indeed, the Razuna wiki page has very good information. Based on it, I created the following script to compile ffmpeg on Amazon Linux: https://gist.github.com/gboudreau/f24aed76b4cc91bfb2c1